# Exhaustively permutate a vector of size 20 in Matlab

Tags: algorithm, matlab, vector, permutation

I'm trying to exhaustively permutate a vector of size 20, but when I tried to use `perms(v)`, I get the error

```
  Error using perms (line 23)
  Maximum variable size allowed by the program is exceeded.
```

I've read from the documentation that the memory required for vectors longer than 10 is astronomical. So I'm looking for an alternative.

What I'm trying to do is the following (using a smaller scale example, where the vector here is only of size 3 instead of 20) - find all vectors, x, of length 3 where `(x_i)^2 = 1`, e.g.

```
  (1, 1, 1), 
  (-1, 1, 1), (1, -1, 1), (1, 1, -1),
  (-1, -1, 1), (-1, 1, -1), (1, -1, -1),
  (-1, -1, -1)
```

I was trying to iteratively create the "base vector", where the number of '-1' elements increased from 0 to 20, then use `perms(v)` to permutate each "base vector", but I ran into the memory problem.

Is there any alternative to do this?

Comment: So, in your actual case with size 20, are you still following the rule : `(x_i)^2 = 1` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2^20 such vectors (about 1 million). So you can make a cycle with counter in range 0..2^20-1 and map counter value (binary representation) to needed vector (zero bit to -1, one bit to +1 or vice versa). Simple mapping formula:

```
Vector_Element = bit * 2  - 1
```

Example for length 4:

```
 i=10 
 binary form  1  0 1  0
 +/-1 vector: 1 -1 1 -1
```